# How to loop array of objects and display a simple table html?

Tags: angular

The array key and values are unknown so it should be ideal to any array of object. I probably can loop over first object, take all the keys for the header of my table. Than loop from the beginning and insert all values for each object. I'm asking if there is a nice way to do it inside the html

my array: `[{key1: value1, key2, value1}, {key1: value2, key2: value2}]`

The output html:

```
key1 | key 2
value1  value1
value2  value2
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at `*ngFor` ?

Comment: As almost everything else, it's done in part in the HTML template, and in part in the TS code. Try doing it first, then if your solution doesn't work or isn't good enough, then post your code, and ask. But there's really no reason to try avoiding writing TypeScript code as much as possible. Your strategy looks good to me, and doesn't require much code at all.